# Resolve SSIS error on simple Execute Process Task 0xC0029151 for CMD

Tags: ssis

I have `Error: 0xC0029151 at Execute Process Task` on Simplest Execute Process Task for calling CMD to create file. I bit surprised that I could not find any solution online or in MS docs. The only thing I figured out that this error can arise on any other tasks as well.
My global task is to create Config file using package var, so for this reason I'm calling `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` to create file with set of `echo ..> myfile.txt`.  I'm kind gave up on solving this problem which I suspect doesn't have clear definite cause or solution. Appreciate if anybody can point me to other avenues. I've tested my Executable path OK, I'm on my own machine with admin rights. Below some screenshots from my packs.  I tested this flow as single task and connected to others which worked OK before. Same result.
Note that when cmd called command windows opened on totally diff ...IDE path.
all combos of option /arguments

no code

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I afraid it's simple. Try to use /C flag:

`CMD.exe requires an additional argument /C while executing command line commands in Execute Process Task. Otherwise, It will not execute the given command.`
[More info here](https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/executing-msdos-commands-in-ssis/)

Answer (score 1):

When I looked up the SSIS error code, I found it pops up almost exclusively when the number of errors has exceeded the maximum allowable number of errors. Then I looked up the CMD.EXE exit code and found this explanation of the code:

> The application terminated as a result of a CTRL+C. Indicates that the
>   application has been terminated either by user's keyboard input CTRL+C
>   or CTRL+Break or closing command prompt window.

I initially thought that you'd probably just need to increase the maximum number of errors allowed, but then I started thinking about a similar problem I had when interfacing with the Windows system from inside SSIS. I was trying to create new files, and then check if the file existed. My problem was that SSIS wasn't waiting for the file creation to finish, and tried to check the existence of the file too quickly, before the file had been written. So I added a simple wait after I issued the create file command.

Try adding a small wait after the `echo ..> myfile.txt` command. I'd try 500ms and go from there to find the right interval.