# Exception: -1073573551 in the SSIS Package Execution

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssis, sql-server-agent, executeprocesstask

I have a SSIS package [Target Version 2012]. In one of the Execute Process Task Attribute, I am calling a .bat file.
The Package executes without any error when I execute it using the Visual Studio. But the same SSIS Package fails to execute with below error when I configure the SSIS Package inside the SQL Server Agent Job.

> Error: 2024-03-20 11:21:49.13     Code: 0xC0029151     Source: UnZip eDelivery Results Files (Post-ControlM Job) Execute Process Task     Description: In Executing "\NVCS-SQL-02\SSISPackages\Syndicated\UnZipTool\UnZipTool_Syndicated_1_NVCS_US.bat" "" at "", The process exit code was "-532459699" while the expected was "0".  End Error

Comment: How should we help you with finding the cause of the error on execution of `UnZipTool_Syndicated_1_NVCS_US.bat` without seeing the lines in this batch file? You can use yourself a www search engine and search for `SSIS 0xC0029151` or `SSIS "-532459699"` if you don't want to share the code in the batch file with us. The first link on the www search results page is [Resolve SSIS error on simple Execute Process Task 0xC0029151 for CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721916/). It is recommended to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "UnZipTool_Syndicated_1_NVCS_US.bat"`.